# Where can I ask this question about a life choice?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've tried the Chemistry Exchange and they suggested the academia exchange and the academia exchange suggested asking meta and in both of those exchanges I was told my question was off topic. My question is a life choice about two different awards and which one to take. Where on StackExchange can I ask it?

**The Description:**

As part of my Chemistry A Level Techniquest has given me the opportunity to do 70 hours of a task with a group and if done correctly I could gain a Gold CREST award which can be put on my CV for Uni.

As part of my gold CREST award I must do talks to High Schools and primary school children on why Chemistry is fun but also important to everyday life. I thought this could be really enjoyable but....

I am also doing a Silver Duke of Edinburgh at the same time. I want to take Science related courses in University and revising for A Levels at the same time as doing a GOLD CREST award and Duke of Edinburgh seems really difficult.

I was thinking I should drop one but which one should I drop?

Is it even possible to do revision, and both challenges at the same time?

Which is better to put on a CV?

What option gives me more life skills?

Comment: In general the SE sites try to collect questions and answers that are valuable for future visitors. That makes that personal advice, and that is a bit how your question reads, will not fly well on most of the SE sites.

Comment: This is off-topic in any relevant SE site as a request for specific advice that depends on your exact circumstances, and a *too broad* one at that. As rene  says, it is highly unlikely to help anybody else or to be answerable in the SE format.

Comment: I haven't even heard of Gold Crest before, but from the little cursory research I've done on it it seems more prestigious/ less commonly than the DofE, even the Gold one. Based on that I'd personally say drop the DofE, but honestly, instead of just taking my lone word on it, I'd recommend you ask this over at TheStudentRoom.co.uk, this is their field of expertise.

Comment: @Hashim I have asked and I havent had a single reply in 3 days :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain things don't *quite* fit into existing sites yet. Academia's more focused towards career academicians, and highschooler.se is not a thing that I recall ever being suggested.

I'm going to make a *radical* suggestion though.

Go talk to your form teacher (or equivalent). If nothing else, they either have more experience with these things or can refer you to someone who does. There's just so many specifics here that it is really better to ask someone who knows both *you* and the *system* to decide on the best course of action, rather than a random internet person.